# Date comparison in bash scripting

Tags: bash

What is the problem in that loop please?

```
while read result
do
    filenames[ $j ]="$result"
    filedates[ $j ]=$(stat -c %y ${filenames[ $j ]} | cut -d ' ' -f1)

    (( j++ ))
done << (ls -t *.gz)
```

I am getting this error:

```
script.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script.sh: line 13: `done << (ls -t *.gz)'
```

Comment: Not at all clear what you mean.  Is each of file2 through file5 the same age, which is 5 days older than file1?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're attempting to use [Process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), but not quite doing it correctly.

You need:

```
while read result
do
    filenames[ $j ]="$result"
    filedates[ $j ]=$(stat -c %y ${filenames[ $j ]} | cut -d ' ' -f1)
    (( j++ ))
done < <(ls -t *.gz)
```

Note the critical differences in the spacing on the `done` line.  You redirect with a single `<`; you then use the `<(...)` for process substitution.  Using `<<` means the code is looking for a 'here document'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are have GNU coreutils:

```
stat -c "%Y %n" * | awk '{print $2, (prev ? (prev-$1)/86400 " days" : ""); prev=$1}'
```

Given these files:

```
touch file1.tar.gz
touch -t 01041200 file2.tar.gz
touch -t 1312311200 file3.tar.gz
touch -t 1312261200 file4.tar.gz
touch -t 1312211200 file5.tar.gz
```

output:

```
$ stat -c "%Y %n" * | awk '{print $2, (prev ? (prev-$1)/86400 " days" : ""); prev=$1}'
file1.tar.gz
file2.tar.gz 5.18753 days
file3.tar.gz 4 days
file4.tar.gz 5 days
file5.tar.gz 5 days
```

Comment: thanks alot thats work fine

final questions please

am using this loop
while read result
do
filenames[ $j ]="$result"
filedates[ $j ]=$(stat -c %y ${filenames[ $j ]} | cut -d ' ' -f1)

(( j++ ))
done << (ls -t *.gz)

i got this error
script.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script.sh: line 12: `done << (ls -t *.gz)'

Comment: you can't post formatted code in a comment: please update the question